# use IEnumertor or IEnumerable c# interface?

Tags: java, c#, interface, enumeration, code-translation

I am porting some Java code to C# and my question is

One of my Java class declarations looks like this:

```
private class PseudoEnumeration implements Enumeration
```

Should this be translated to

```
private class PseudoEnumeration : IEnumerator
```

or

```
private class PseudoEnumeration : IEnumerable
```

and why each case?

Another thing is that the enumerator classes work differently in java and C#. Java has "hasMoreElements" and "nextElement" while C# uses "MoveNext" and "Current".

How would I port a Java function of this form to C#?

```
public boolean hasMoreElements() {
        return (field.hasMoreElements() );
    }
```

EDIT: I know MoveNext returns Bool if field has no more elements. However, it also advances the field to the enumerator to the next element. How do I just check if it has more elements without advancing the enumerator?

Comment: none of them. Use one of the many built-in collections provided by the .Net Framework. as opposed to reinventing the wheel.

Comment: "How do I just check if it has more elements without advancing the enumerator?" You don't.  With most iterators it's not possible to determine if there are any more items without actually knowing what the next item is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given the current `Enumeration` implementation in Java, you should implement the [`IEnumerator<T>` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ienumerator%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), which is the class that enumerates over a collection and provides the methods better fitted to the Java counterpart.

`MoveNext` for example returns `bool` whether there actually is a next value in the enumeration, and relates to the `hasMoreElements` method of Java's `Enumeration`.

The `IEnumerable<T>` interface does not expose any of the details regarding the current state of the enumeration, like `Current` or `MoveNext`; it only exposes a `GetEnumerator` method that returns an `IEnumerator<T>` implementation for the given `IEnumerable<T>`.

Hence, it *is* the `IEnumerator<T>` class the one that exposes *how* to iterate over the collection, the current element, and whether there are more, similar to the `Enumeration` interface in Java.

Answer (score 3):

If you have a specific type it enumerates, it should implement `IEnumerable<T>`.

Answer (score 1):

In C# if you want to look at next element without advancing the enumerator.

LinkedList will give more control while you are looping

You can also use Queue but be careful with this collection because every call to dequeue removes item from list. this collection has peek method.